# Rerender Dynamic Elements when using jQuery Plugin Selectize and Bootstrap-Switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, rerender

I am new to jQuery so please go easy, I have a form that will represent an Advanced Search. Users will be able to add rows to refine their specific search.

Each row has 3 elements: A Checkbox & 2 x Select boxes.
As can be seen in the fiddle I am using jquery to clone the row and place the cloned row after the last row.

Everything is working fine except visually I would like the checkbox to use Bootstrap-Switch http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

And the select boxes to use Selectize https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js

Now, when I clone the row with these plugins not active, everything works.
I have NO idea how to re-render or re activate them once a new row is inserted.

Is this something that is plugin specific? Or kind of universal to jquery?
I have read HEAPS of answers on here about similar things but I cannot seem to get it right.

Here is the jquery snippet:

```
$adSearchForm = $('#adSearchForm');
$adSearchForm.on('click', 'button, input, select, option', function (event) {  
console.log("Button Clicked", event)
});

$('#addSearchRow').click(function(event){
    $('[data-content=adSearch-3]:first').clone().insertAfter('[data-content=adSearch-3]:last');
//  $('.searchByField,.searchOperator').selectize({refreshItems: true});
//  $('[data-toggle=switch]').bootstrapSwitch({refreshItems: true});
});
```

Here is the fiddle, hope its ok. http://jsfiddle.net/CkVQr/6/

Thankyou very much for your help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

### Plugins change your HTML

There are two major problems you may not be fully aware of with your code:

1. Whenever you do a `.clone()` it merely deep clones your DOM element subtree, but not **any event handlers** bound to cloned elements.
2. Your `.selectize()` plugin changes HTML of your form quite considerably, converting input elements to other things. So whenever you clone your already converted select filter row, and subsequently want to run `.selectize()` on it again, this particular plugin won't find any suitable input elements to convert. Hence it won't work. Everything will just look as it should but won't work.

### What can be done?

The main idea is that whenever you clone your search filter row, you have to **clone your original HTML** and not after it was converted using your plugins.

#### HTML Templates to the rescue

One of the possibilities is to change you page (and functionality) a bit and put your search filter row in a template and always use that. When you create your first row, you should read the template (and cache it) and add+convert it on your page. When you'd add an additional row, just use the same cached template and add+convert it again.

**HTML template**

```
<script id="filterRow" type="text/x-template">
    <!-- Your filter rown HTML goes in here -->
</script>
```

**Some Javascript**

```
var cachedTemplate = cachedTemplate || $("#filterRow").html();

...

$('#addSearchRow').click(function(evt) {
    var newRow = cachedTemplate.clone(); // clone for reusability
    newRow.insertAfter('[data-content=adSearch-3]:last');
    newRow.selectize();
    ...
});
```